# Error using Single signon from Okta tile: Cannot POST /implicit/callback

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, okta

I am following the instructions from https://github.com/okta/samples-js-react and I am unable to login to my sample application. Below is how my Okta application profile looks: [image: Okta application details]

My App.js looks like this:

```
  render(){
      return (
        <Router>
            <Security
              issuer="https://dev-xxxxxx.okta.com/oauth2/default"
              client_id="xxxxxxxxxxxx" 
              redirect_uri={window.location.origin + '/implicit/callback'}
              pkce={true} 
            >
                <Navbar />
                <Container text style={{ marginTop: '7em' }}>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/implicit/callback" component={LoginCallback} />
                    <SecureRoute path="/messages" component={Messages} />
                    <SecureRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
                </Container>
            </Security>
        </Router>
      )
  }
```

I get the following error when logging in from the Okta tile.

```
Cannot POST /implicit/callback
```

Comment: Can you try changing your initiate login URI to just be `http://localhost:8080` and see if that helps?

Comment: Then i get the error: Cannot POST /

Comment: Are you using Create React App? If so, the port should be 3000. Here's a quick way to test your Okta configuration with Create React App: https://github.com/oktadeveloper/schematics#react

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved by adding the following config:

```
response_type: "code"
```